# android failed to show result

Tags: android

In following code i want to crate a file in sdcard. but it not giving any valid output. showing only the hello world...Where the "file created" message will be displayed and where the file will be stored?

```
package com.read;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class read extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";
    try{
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}

    System.out.println("File created");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method you're trying to create a file in phone's internal memory.

Just use this code:

```
FileOuputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/" + FILENAME );
```

It will create a file in a root folder of your SD card.

Answer (score 2):

try below code might help you

```
try {
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (root.canWrite()){
    File gpxfile = new File(root, "gpxfile.gpx");
    FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
    out.write("Hello world");
    out.close();
}
}catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**Note:** *For this to be working your emulator or device must have SDcard*

Edit: For reading the file fromSDCard

```
try{

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filename.txt");
   fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
   BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
   String readString = new String(); 
   //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
   while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
      Log.d("line: ", readString);
   }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how do i modify this code to read the file content and display it in emulator? TIA